# KMDF: Handling IRQ

Tags: windows, driver, kmdf, nt

We need to handle IRQ in KMDF driver

I've registered EVT_WDF_DEVICE_RESOURCE_REQUIREMENTS_QUERY callback function but system does not call it.

EVT_WDF_DEVICE_PREPARE_HARDWARE is called without any resources allocated.
Attempt to call WdfInterruptCreate() here results STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_STATE

What is the right way to get free IRQ number from system and attach an interrupt  handler?

**Upd:**

After we have successfully created WDFINTERRUPT object in our AddDevice handler system still does not ask us about resources (EVT_WDF_DEVICE_RESOURCE_REQUIREMENTS_QUERY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion on [social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b346761d-a274-4300-b504-c318b742d982/kmdf-handling-irq?forum=wdk) we've found only one solution: use another OS